# Check checkbox when table cell clicked

Tags: javascript, events, checkbox

I have a table with rows that look like this: ( 'o' is a checkbox)

```
_________________________________________
| o |  some label  | textarea  |    o    |
|___|______________|___________|_________|
```

Now I want to check the left checkbox when the cell it's in is clicked.

I managed to let this happen, but somehow now the checkbox itself won't (un-)check if it's clicked.

**EDIT, possible Solution:**

This is the javascript code I've written:

```
const hefte = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
    hefte.forEach(e => {
      e.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const checkbox = e.parentNode.querySelector('.checkboxfirst input');
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
      });
    });

const ausgabe = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxfirst');
ausgabe.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const checkbox = e.parentNode.querySelector('.checkboxfirst input');
      if (event.eventPhase == '3') {
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
      }
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  });
});

const cb = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
cb.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const checkbox = e.closest('tr').querySelector('.checkbox input');
      if (event.eventPhase == '3') {
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
      }
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  });
});
```

and here's the html:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered>
  @foreach ($labels as $label) 
    <tr>
      <td class="checkboxfirst"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[{{ $loop->index }}]one /> 
      <td>{{ $label }}</td>
      <td class="with-textarea"><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox[{{ $loop->index }}]two" /></td> 
    </tr>
  @foreach
</table>
```

but I think this is bad code because of the repeated `checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked`.

**Is there a way to avoid the repeating code?**

Comment: I've come up with this, so far, but the version using the `<table>` layout doesn't seem to work as you/I want it to so far: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/owqLfexg/1/

Comment: @DavidThomas the problem is, I can't change anything about the layout. It has to be a table and it has to be like this

Answer (score 0):

I will be writing from the back of my head but I think what is happening is when you click checkbox, it sets, but at the same time event on the row is reverting this. As a result, it looks like nothing happened, while 2 things happened.

Try grabbing `event` and prevent default. If you click in the input itself then it will be handled by JS anyway.

```
const cb = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxfirst');
cb.forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       const checkbox = e.closest('tr').querySelector('.checkboxfirst input');
       checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    });
  });
```

[*the code above was adjusted during edit*]

(Side note: if this is dynamic list, you might consider moving listener into a variable so you can remove it when element is removed. Otherwise, it might lead to memory leak.)

[*edit*]

As question was expanded, this is the expanded part of the answer. Now I think that if you click checkbox then it’s parentNode is not `<tr>` but cell itself, hence querySelector will not be able to find `.checkbox input`. Method `closest('tr')` will find the first matching parent (or parent of parent, etc.).

Basically, the same thing should be done for the other checkbox, as well.

```
const cb = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
cb.forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       const checkbox = e.closest('tr').querySelector('.checkbox input');
       checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    });
  });
```

Comment: this brought up some problems with the other table cell+checkbox on the right

Comment: What's the purpose of the check-box on the right, it doesn't seem to connect to anything in the provided code; is it something we need to affect as well?

Comment: @DavidThomas it's a checkbox that needs to be checked if the textarea next to it is empty, the left checkbox indicates that either the textarea or the other checkbox has to be filled

Comment: So should the left checkbox toggle a required attribute, or is that out-of-scope?

Comment: accidently edited this answer instead of the question, ignore it please ._.

Comment: @DavidThomas it doesn't matter. The checkbox should be checked when the table cell it's placed in is clicked. Pretending as if the checkbox is as big as the cell itself

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon, I expanded my answer because question was expanded but also I saw additional things today.

Comment: I am still unable to uncheck the left checkbox when clicking on it, the right one doesn't get checked at all